# Time zone trouble

Tags: android

Am trying to get week data from calendar using the code

```
public static String[] getpreviousweek(Context context, int num) {

    Log.e("/////////////////", returnPositionIndex(context)+"");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(PrefUtil.getFragYear(context));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(PrefUtil.getFragMonth(context));
    int day = Integer.parseInt(PrefUtil.getFragDay(context));
    Log.e("Year", year + " ");
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"),Locale.UK);
    c.set(year, month, day);
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);
    // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String[] days = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        days[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    return days;
}
```

The value of num is zero.. The problem is am getting proper value in motorola devices and getting it wrong in nexus..cant figure out a solution...

Somebody please help me to sort it out

Comment: Please refrain from using 'abbreviations' such as "plm" and "soln". It takes 1 second to type the words, just do it

Comment: Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) 's `DateTime.minusWeeks(num)`.

Comment: edited...........................

Comment: @Geethu ...is my solution not working for you??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha nope...

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code

```
 Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
 String AM_PM;

  if(ci.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0)
    {
         AM_PM ="AM";
    }
    else
    {
         AM_PM ="PM";
    }
    String CiDateTime = "" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
        (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
        ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+AM_PM;

     System.out.println("time=========================================="+CiDateTime);
```

**Output:-**

```
time==========================================2015-11-24 PM
```